# Convert multidimension array to different arrays in javascript

Tags: arrays

I have an array in javascript shown below

```
var multiArray = [['Jan',12],['Feb',13],['Mar',14]];
```

Now i want the elements of the above array elements into two seperate arrays as

```
var array1 = ['Jan','Feb','Mar'];
var array2 = [12,13,14];
```

Which methodology should i use to convert them as separate arrays.?

Comment: There is also a similar question. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507440/divide-a-2d-array-into-multiple-arrays-using-a-separator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Divide a 2D array into multiple arrays using a separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507440/divide-a-2d-array-into-multiple-arrays-using-a-separator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Map to convert them

```js
const multiArray = [['Jan',12],['Feb',13],['Mar',14]];
const m = new Map(multiArray);
const arr1 = Array.from(m.keys());
const arr2 = Array.from(m.values());

console.log(arr1, arr2);
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case this is the easiest approach:

```
var multiArray = [['Jan',12],['Feb',13],['Mar',14]];

var arr1 = multiArray.map(x => x[0])
var arr2 = multiArray.map(x => x[1])
```